# gwan dynamic buffer, how often to use and when should you not use it?

Tags: http, dynamic, g-wan

I have seen the xbuf from gwan. Not sure when it is not a good use for it. Can it be used for integers or float? When is it not recommended to be used? I am very much inclined to use it as often as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an **application server**, G-WAN is expected to generate *dynamic contents*.

In this case, the server is building a reply served to clients.

Part of these `dynamic contents` are binary (like pictures) and this is why G-WAN offers a native ultra-fast *in-memory* GIF, [charts](http://gwan.ch/source/charts.c), and frame-buffer API. More complex images can be generated with general-purpose libraries like Cairo (used by Internet browsers).

But most `dynamic contents` are text (like HTML pages, JSON payloads, etc.).

And this is the purpose of the G-WAN `xbuffer` API which works as an extended `snprintf()` - supporting `strings`, `integers`, `floats`, `base64`, `hexdump`, `binary` formating (3 => "11") and more.

The [loan.c](http://gwan.ch/source/loan.c) example illustrates very well how relevant, fast and versatile xbuffers are.

> when should you not use it?

When sending an empyt reply (HTTP status code 204), or (less likely but still possible) when appending data directly in a previously resized **reply** buffer. G-WAN examples show how to do that, look at the [fractal.c](http://gwan.ch/source/fractal.c) file.